# Problem adding an item into a 2 dimension List in C# (unexpected behavior)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, generics

Can you tell me why am I getting the following result from this code

```
 public static void CountSort(List<List<string>> arr)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count / 2; i++)
         arr[i][1] = "-";

     List<List<string>> result = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<string>(), arr.Count).ToList();

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
     {
         string tempValue = arr[i][1];
         int index = int.Parse(arr[i][0]);
         result[index].Add(tempValue);
     }
}
```

The result is multi dimension List of strings. Whenever the loop goes through, it adds that temp value to all of the sub arrays rather than adding it to the one I want to add it based on index.

I am breaking my head now trying to figure out why is that.

Output looks something like this:

```
List<List<string>("1"), List<string>("1"),List<string>("1")>
```

Output I am expecting is :

```
List<List<string>(), List<string>("1"), List<string>()>
```

Comment: What does the parameter `arr` contain on input?

Comment: it contains a list or lists with 2 items one is numeric second is letter. Like so ("1", "test"),("2", "test")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
result = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<string>(), arr.Count).ToList();
```

This creates **one** `List<string>` instance and repeats this instance in the resulting enumerable/list. Again, **only one** `List<string>` instance is being created here. Regardless which index you are using on *result* to get a sub list, it's always the **same** *List<string>* instance.

Thus, your code adds the temp values to all sub lists, because all the sub lists are in reality just the same single *List<string>* instance.

Solution: Instead of using `Enumerable.Repeat` (which just repeats the given *List<string>* instance instead of creating new *List<string>* instances) just do it the old-fashioned way and create all the required *List<string>* instances yourself:

```
List<List<string>> result = new();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; ++i)
    result.Add(new List<string>());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. That mush be because the New List<string>() is the reference type and we add the pointers to that 2 diminution list. That makes sense once you put it down like that. Thank you again!